# Half-bridge driver ground loop elimination

Tags: mosfet-driver, isolation, ground-loop, half-bridge

I built this half-bridge driver using a generic Schmitt trigger/hex inverter IC and a 555 timer as the square wave generator. By varying the value of the resistors, the dead time can be adjusted and it works perfectly!

The outputs are connected to the input of a [TC4420](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21419D.pdf) MOSFET driver IC. One for each output. I thought this would work by using two (galvanically-isolated) power supplies for each of the TC4420s but then realized that a ground loop still exists between the input signals.

Is there a way I can eliminate this ground loop without optocouplers? Optocouplers are slow and even the fast ones might draw more current than the hex inverter can output.

[image: half-bridge driver]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuitry isn't going to work. Even with isolated supplies. The fundamental issue is that the logic input reference is common to the MOSFET gate return. What you need is a high-side gate driver with bootstrap to drive an N-channel MOSFET. What you really need is a half-bridge driver that includes the bootstrap diode. There are so many to choose from including high-voltage versions (up to ~600VDC). Some even include adjustable deadtime. TBH, the whole left side of you circuit (everything except you power stage) could be replaced with a single 8-pin gate drive and boot capacitor.

You probably want something like this if you have no idea what I'm talking about: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27712-q1.pdf?ts=1706252591500&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC27712-Q1

I don't know your requirements, but there are plenty of options available: High-voltage, built in shoot-through protection, single input, independent gate control, fixed dead-time, adjustable dead time, programable slew rate if you want to get fancy, ect. All the big names make these: TI, ADI, Infinium, Microchip Tech, OnSemi, ect.

Comment: I have some IRS2513D's but their dead time wasn't enough to compensate for the MOSFETs' rise/fall times even with no gate resistor.  There was still a decent bit of overlap. That's why I decided to (attempt) to make my own. However, what if I did try to put a super fast optocoupler like the 6N137A in between the logic output and the input of the MOSFET driver?

https://www.vishay.com/docs/84131/6n137a.pdf

Comment: @ElectronicsNoob You certainly can make that work. Not typically done this way, but what you want to do is put whole TC4420 circuitry on the isolated (right) side of the 6N137A along with an independent power supply. The power supply has to be isolated from the rest of the circuit (logic and low-side FET) because its local ground has to ride on the switched-node. Then, you treat the logic (left) side of the 6N137A like the rest of your logic and that gets tied to the low-side (system) ground.

Comment: @ElectronicsNoob keep in mind, depending on your speed requirements, that additional isolator may add around 75ns of prop delay. May or may not matter but a trick to compensate that, move one of your high-side invertors to the low-side train - should look like 1 invertor on the high-side and 3 on the bottom side. 2 NOT gate prop delays should be around 75ns, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The IRS2153D didn't have enough source/sink current(180mA/260mA) capability to drive a ~5000pF load so I turned to the TC4420. I needed something to drive it so here I am now. On second thought I could drive two TC4420s with the IRS2153D in a half-bridge configuration powered by isolated power supplies. I am going to try that first and then come back to this optocoupler business. Also, why would I need to compensate for the optocoupler delay if there is two, one for HS and one for LS?

Comment: @ElectronicsNoob the LS is system-ground referenced. You don't need isolation for the low-side driver.  Sure, you can "isolate" the LS. But you don't have to and you already have usable logic from your shoot-through control that was available - it simplifies the design.